# Solr home directory not found

Tags: ubuntu, solr, solr6

After I change owner of Solr core directory in /var/solr/data 
I cannot start solr service again.

```
su[1706]: Solr home directory /var/solr/data not found!
su[1706]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for use...lr
systemd[1]: solr.service: control process exited, code...=1
systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Controls Apache Solr ...e.
systemd[1]: Unit solr.service entered failed state.
```

How to reset owner of that directory?

I have changed owner to root, but solr keep show this error.

Comment: Can you please add the error to your question?

Comment: Oh ya sorry I forgot @MatteoAlessani

Answer (score 1):

yeah, it is better (required for many dirs) for solr process to be the owner of those dirs. Do this and restart:

```
sudo chown -R solr:solr /var/solr/data
```

Comment: @AdnanFajri Did you ever fix this? I am having the same problem; I can confirm that the `solr` user is assigned as the owner via `ls -l` but I'm still getting the error